# Is distorted calligraphy used in the season 1 opening of Ushio to Tora?

Tags: symbolism, ushio-to-tora

The opening sequence of the first season of anime series *Ushio to Tora* contains a series of images which might be distorted calligraphy, sort of like what Picasso might have done. There are a set of 6 varied-color frames, a short vertically scrolling sequence, and finally the title, which is clearly calligraphic and much less distorted. After that, the credits actually begin, now in a normal Japanese font.  Here some are:

First:
[image: possible calligraphy 1, red]

Second:
[image: possible calligraphy 2, green]

Seventh:
[image: possible calligraphy 7, vertical scroll red]

Title:
[image: calligraphic title plate]

You can see them all beginning at time mark 4:30 of [episode 1](http://www.crunchyroll.com/ushio-and-tora/episode-1-the-fate-that-brings-ushio-and-tora-together-682425). The *Seventh* one is partial, a single shot from a short, vertical scrolling sequence.

I don't know if these are distorted calligraphy or not.  But going backwards beginning at the *Title* plate, there certainly appears to be a commonality of design. If they are calligraphic, are they legible?  If so I imagine they would be concepts such as **courage**, **fate**, etc.

If they are not calligraphic, what are they?  Do they symbolize something I should recognize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could describe this as calligraphic. I don't know enough to say whether this is what a calligrapher would consider genuine art vs. just being writing with bold and swishy brush strokes.

This writing doesn't "symbolize" anything, though - it's just the lyrics of the first verse of the OP theme as they're being sung.

1. 混ぜんな *mazen na*
2. 危険な *kiken-na*
3. やつらが会いすりゃ *yatsura-ga ai-surya*
4. 土壇場 *dotanba*
5. 土壇場 *dotanba*
6. じゃないか *janai ka*
7. 混ぜるな危険のねんごろ *mazeru na kiken-no nengoro* (written bottom-to-top)

I don't want to venture a translation here, but see e.g. [Lyrical Nonsense](http://www.lyrical-nonsense.com/lyrics/kinniku-shojo-tai/mazeru-na-kiken/) for one candidate translation.

Comment: Thanks! I was not even sure if it was writing. It was so blobby my mind was trying to identify shapes, like one does with clouds. In *First* I thought I might have identified two elements. The 2nd character from upper left kind of looks like a kid falling backwards, holding a purse with outstretched arms. Then the 2nd character diagonally away from lower right reminded me of a cartoon hedgehog. So if I could "see" those things, I was wondering what else I might be missing. At the same time I suspected it was writing, though.